# AdControl error: No ad available. In Microsoft Advertising for mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, ads

I am making app for windows phone 8 and use Microsoft Advertising for mobile. For this I am using Link https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-windows-phone-silverlight

All thing is well, but problem is that when i am using their ApplicationId and AdUnitId, the ad will show and i use new created ApplicationId and AdUnitId then error is show- AdControl error: No ad available.This error is in both live and developement mode. Please guide me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, the fill rate is very low (not many companies pay for having their ads shown on Windows Phone). Make sure you enabled auto refresh and wait. Try navigating to another page and back. For me an ad usually appears after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your App published and available in the store? Sometimes it will take 1-2 days and then it will show ads by real units. Please wait for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue a couple of months ago and I contacted Microsoft and this is their answer:

> Some region may not display and ad due to the region not having an ad available.
>
> Generally the US region has large ad inventory so this is generally a good region to test your ad units.

Perhaps, you have the same issue.