# WinRT - Microsoft Advertising ads don't show up

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store

I'm trying to add ads to my app's shared page (is used both by the `.Windows` and `.WindowsPhone` projects. It's in the `.Shared` project). I'm trying to do it using the code-behind `.cs` file to make it 'universal'. Here's the code:

```
...
using Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI;
...
        private void ShowAd()
        {
            var ac = new AdControl();
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            ac.ApplicationId = "92xxxb";
            ac.AdUnitId = "3xxx8";
            ac.Width = 320;
            ac.Height = 50;
#else
            ac.ApplicationId = "38xxx8";
            ac.AdUnitId = "3xxx6";
            ac.Width = 728;
            ac.Height = 90;
#endif
            adArea.Children.Add(ac);
            ac.IsAutoRefreshEnabled = true;
            ac.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            ac.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        }
```

The thing is, it only shows a black box in the `AdArea`. No clue why, the IDs are 100% correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add a handler to ErrorOcurred event do you get an error?

Comment: Yeah I get an error: `No ad available. No additional info.` Not sure why. Other apps don't have this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106753/adcontrol-error-no-ad-available-in-microsoft-advertising-for-mobile

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I didn't get a single view in the last 6 months. Are there that few ads available? I'll try changing the app's category or something.

Comment: @Reynevan, Can you provide your **Application Id** and **Ad Unit Id** here? I will help you to check if there is some issue with it. Thanks

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFTYep, turns out the ad unit was broken. THe new one generated more money than the last one did in 6 months of its existance.